# Terminal command to enable write to remote NFTS drive

Tags: macos, terminal, ntfs, disk-volume

Can the *drivename* be "Seagate Backup Plus Drive" in the Terminal command `... label= drivename none ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse` or will the spaces create errors in Terminal?

Answer (score 1):

If you use quotes in the command the spaces shouldn't create errors. Using

```
... label="Seagate Backup Plus Drive" none ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse
```

should interpret the name as *Seagate Backup Plus Drive* and

```
... label=Seagate Backup Plus Drive none ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse
```

will interpret the name as *Seagate*.

The better solution is to rename the volume to one word without spaces or use an escape sequence like in this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/220922/93229).

Comment: You do not necessarily need to rename the volume as the proper way is to escape the spaces with `\040` not quote the label.  See the man page for fstab.  Last time I tried quoting the name of the volume it didn't work.

Comment: @user3439894 I don't like to type escape sequences in scripts or in the command line. I already linked your answer in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the spaces with `\040`, so it would be as in the following example:

```
LABEL=Seagate\040Backup\040Plus\040Drive none ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse
```

See "EXAMPLES" in `man fstab` from a Terminal.